# C# DateTime to Javascript Date has different result

Tags: javascript, c#

Probably missing something obvious, but I'm getting different dates for the same value:

C#

`myDate -> DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds`

JS

`date = new Date(myDate)`

`date` is parsed to a value in the future, not the same value as `DateTime.Now`

Pretty sure it's timezone related, but can't work out what.

Edit: per my comment, myDate is returned via WebApi, then parsed in JavaScript. I'd expect the result to be the same value as DateTime.Now in the C# line, but it's a date in the near future (ie tomorrow).

Comment: which date are you expected?

Comment: which value in the future ? Very far future ?

Comment: "Pretty sure it's timezone related" What makes you think that ?

Comment: What is myDate value in JS?

Comment: myDate is the milliseconds generated in the C# line. I return that value via a webapi call, then convert it to a JS date, which I'd expect to be the same as the DateTime.Now value, but it's tomorrow.

Comment: @Nathan It's indeed possible that it is time-zone related. What is the exact value printed, with toString() ? In Javascript, you will have the local time printed. You can force to show UTC value. If the difference is a few seconds, however, it might be due to leap seconds.

Comment: C# milliseconds -> 1517509770503.939 
C# datetime.now.tostring() -> 2018-02-01T14:46:20.62Z
JS new Date() from C# milliseconds -> Fri Feb 02 2018 00:46:20 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause - there was an unnecessary Date.UTC() call, which was messing with locales. Removed it, issue is gone.